# drawing using canvas in html 5

Tags: javascript, html

I want to draw 4 coins in a table that consists of 1 row and 2 columns. That means all the rows and all the columns must have all 4 coins. I have written the code as below. But it is giving the unexpected result. i.e., the coins are displaying in only 2 column ...plz help me..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>    <canvas id="r1c1" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
            </canvas>
    </td>
    <td>    <canvas id="r1c2" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
            </canvas>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var img,c,s;
var posX=0,posY=0;

var canvasA= document.getElementById("r1c1");
canvasA.addEventListener("onafterprint",placeA(),false); 

var canvasB= document.getElementById("r1c2");
canvasB.addEventListener("onafterprint",placeB(),false);


function placeA()
{
c=document.getElementById("r1c1");
s = c.getContext("2d");
img = new Image();
img.onload= drawimage();
}

function placeB()
{
c=document.getElementById("r1c2");
s = c.getContext("2d");
img = new Image();
img.onload= drawimage();
}
function drawimage()
{ 
img.src="coin.jpg";
img.addEventListener("load",function(){s.drawImage(img,30,0,40,20)},false);
img.addEventListener("load",function(){s.drawImage(img,0,30,40,20)},false);
img.addEventListener("load",function(){s.drawImage(img,60,30,40,20)},false);
img.addEventListener("load",function(){s.drawImage(img,30,70,40,20)},false);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `placeB` function replace variable `s` which is stored globally as image loading is asynchronous.

You need to pass the context variable in the function `drawImage` to use correct context for `placeA` and `placeB`

```
function placeA()
{
    c=document.getElementById("r1c1");
    s = c.getContext("2d");
    img = new Image();
    img.onload= drawimage(s);
}

function placeB()
{
    c=document.getElementById("r1c2");
    s = c.getContext("2d");
    img = new Image();
    img.onload= drawimage(s);
}
function drawimage(s)
{ 
    img.src="coin.jpg";
    img.addEventListener("load",function(){s.drawImage(img,30,0,40,20)},false);
    img.addEventListener("load",function(){s.drawImage(img,0,30,40,20)},false);
    img.addEventListener("load",function(){s.drawImage(img,60,30,40,20)},false);
    img.addEventListener("load",function(){s.drawImage(img,30,70,40,20)},false);
}
```